# Multiple calls to API runs a script too fast for the first script to finish before the next one starts

Tags: php, jquery, sql, locking

I've got a script that is called from an API. The problem I'm having is that the script is being called too many times within a short period of time, 1/1000 of a second at times. In my script, I have sql queries that do some deletions and updates depending on the times that someone schedules a playlist.

The process is as follows:

- Add as many playlists
- Click the 'save playlist schedule' button.
- Use API call for each playlist created.

Seems simple, however, if 2 or more playlists are created (then 2 or more API calls are made), the queries aren't running linearly so the database isn't changing to the desired numbers.

I've edited the Jquery to sleep for a second each time just to ensure that this was the problem and it was, however, I don't want to limit frequency that this API call can be made.

I tried to create a lock file like so in php at the very beginning of the script that is run:

```
 # -----ENSURES USERS DON'T CALL THE API TOO MANY TIMES---------
        # Check lock file so someone can't overwrite database before edits are done.
        do
        {
            $file = fopen('playlist_lock.txt', 'w+');
            if (fgets($file) == 0) // 0 being unlocked, 1 being locked
            {
                fwrite($file, '1');
                fclose($file);
                break;
            }
            usleep(10000);
        }
        while ($is_locked);
```

and then at the very end of the file, I add:

```
fwrite($file, '0');
fclose($file);
```

However, this didn't seem to work. It seemed to lower the problems caused by calling more than 4 or so, but is still problematic for the initial 3 or 4. Meaning, I think the file isn't being written to fast enough regardless to lock the other calls from running just yet.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is to use two file-names for checking/changing lock-status, instead of reading/writing from the same file. Here is the sample code:

```
$locked = 'playlist_lock.txt';
$unlocked = 'playlist_unlock.txt';

if (!file_exists($unlocked) && !file_exists($locked)){
    file_put_contents($unlocked, '1');
}

do {

    if (file_exists($unlocked)){
        rename($unlocked, $locked); // lock if it is unlocked
        break;
    }

    usleep(10000);

} while ($is_locked);
```

and then at the very end of the file:

```
rename($locked, $unlocked); // unlock
```

**Update**

Perhaps, it's better to create `playlist_unlock.txt` manually, than check its existence everytime script runs. So that this block of code can be removed:

```
if (!file_exists($unlocked) && !file_exists($locked)){
    file_put_contents($unlocked, '1');
}
```